# Call Javascript function with multiple parameters from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to send two parameters from PHP to Javascript, but I get second undefined parameter.

```
<?php echo '<button onclick="deleteImage(\'' . $image->photo_id . ',' . $content->content_id . '\')" >Delete</button>'; ?>
```

Please help, thank you

Comment: Please show us the code where $content->content_id is supposedly initialized, if that's the one that's undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forget to escape some `'` :

```
<?php echo '<button onclick="deleteImage(\'' . $image->photo_id . '\',\'' . $content->content_id . '\')" >Delete</button>'; ?>
```